# Can I use Google Sign In only for a selected group of Users?

Tags: javascript, web-applications

i would Like to integrate Google Sign In into my yet to be build WebApp. But I don't want everyone with a Google account to be able to login into my app, but restrict the access to only a selected group of accounts. These accounts share some Characteristics e.g. domain.

Is that possible?

Comment: when you researched google sign in, what did you find?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Once the user tries to login, you check their email address against an allowed list. Easiest to compare against a database table of allowed email addresses, but I have also used Google Sheets so my non-techinical users can control the allowed list.